# Mozilla Persona Authentication

Tags: authentication, browserid

What are the advantages of using Persona if I want to restrict email adresses for accessing a site ?
I have to manage in a same way the authorized email address on my server?
What am missing ?

Answer (score 7):

The two main advantages of using Persona on your site is that:

1. You don't have to store passwords in your database.
2. Your users don't need to pick a password just for your site.

If you want to restrict logins to specific email addresses (or restrict to a specific domain for example), then Persona doesn't really change anything for you. It gives you a verified email address and you still do the check on your own server.

Comment: I'd also add these: 3) You don't have to send verification emails. 4) Your user doesn't have to go through the verification-email process just for your site. (The exception to #4 being if this is the first Persona-enabled site they've seen **and** their email provider doesn't provide its own IdP **and** their email provider isn't supported by BigTent, they'll have to go through Persona's verification process.)

Answer (score 2):

Persona handles authentication for you, but not authorization. In other words, Persona enables you to easily prove the current user actually owns the email address they're passing to you, but it doesn't decide for you if you should give the owner of that email address access to your site.